# Is it Possible to Use Live Preview with Global Settings

Tags: plugin-development, plugins, globals, live-preview

I know that out of the box one cannot use Live Preview with Global Settings.  I am wondering if it is possible to write a plugin or in some other manner get Live Preview to work with Global Settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything's possible, but not without hacking core files, which isn't recommended.

By default, global settings don't even have the concept of a "template", which is a fundamental part of getting a Live Preview request to work.

Comment: Okay -- good to know.